# JTable-SQLite binding problems in Netbeans

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, jdbc

My DB tables update and all that. JTable is all that's left to fix. I'm using Netbeans and I'm attempting to bind my JTable to retrieve records from my database.

I couldn't bind it because it won't connect to my DB.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the right <path> for student.db ??

Comment: @Suzon I assume it is. as I used the same URL in the code to connect to the database. c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:students.db");

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the absolute path of your *.db/.sqlite* file here, to make it work.

```
jdbc:sqlite://<Path>\file.db
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, if the database does not exist, it will create a new database with the same name when you use in java(or any other languages). But when you connect through Netbeans you need to specify the full path to an existing database. You can also download dummy databases (like chinook.db from its official website) to connect.